# example of GeckoFX

Tags: vb.net, xulrunner, geckofx

I downloaded GeckoFX (ver 16), the XULRunner Dotnet wrapper to use in a winForms (VB.NET) application, but there are no instructions on usage anywhere (just the Initialize command).

I added the control onto my form and in the Form load event, put in the following:

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
    Xpcom.Initialize(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "/xulrunner")
    InitializeComponent()

    Me.GeckoWebBrowser1.Enabled = True
    Me.GeckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com")

End Sub
```

Nothing happens. The control is not visible, no navigation takes place. 
Just a simple project (C# is fine too) that shows the control actually working would be nice (please do not answer with another URL that points to GeckoFx's wiki page as it is useless and no examples anywhere are shown)

Answer (score 1):

```
Imports Gecko

Public Class Form1

Private myBrowser As GeckoWebBrowser

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Xpcom.Initialize(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\xulrunner")
    myBrowser = New GeckoWebBrowser()
    myBrowser.Parent = Me.SplitContainer1.Panel2
    myBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    myBrowser.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: the 3rd line should be


    Private WithEvents myBrowser As GeckoWebBrowser


this control does not work as a drag-n-drop toolbox item, I discovered - it can only be defined in code (why no one mentioned this before is anyone's guess)

Answer (score 1):

Just do it with Events. Im talking for `withEvents`:D
    Imports Gecko

```
Public Class Form1

Private WithEvents myBrowser As GeckoWebBrowser

Public Sub New()
InitializeComponent()
Xpcom.Initialize(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\xulrunner")
myBrowser = New GeckoWebBrowser()
myBrowser.Parent = Me.SplitContainer1.Panel2
myBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
myBrowser.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may be a valid answer, you are much more likely to help others by explaining what the code does and how it works. Code-only answers tend to receive less positive attention and aren't as useful as other answers.

Comment: @Aurora0001 1st. Why you think i am new? And ok, thanks for the info!

Comment: You've not got much rep and only registered recently, so it's a fair assumption (though I could be wrong, of course!). Also, if you've not read [answer] yet, it's worth a read to help you write answers that are really useful.

Comment: Thanks for the article, i readed the section "Answering question", it looks that I haven't look at that :D Thanks again!